# What is the "Last trumpet" that Paul was referring to in 1-cor 15:52

Tags: revelation, hermeneutical-approaches, prophecy, referent-identification

Trumpets are mentioned in apocalypse and "Day of the LORD" prophecies. 
E.g

> Psalm 47:5 (God goes up with the sound of a trumpet)
>
> Isaiah 27:13 (God saves his people after a trumpet blast)
>
> Zephaniah 1:16 (The day of the Lord is a day of trumpets and alarm)
>
> Zechariah 9:14 ( God himself blows a trumpet)
>
> Matthew 24:31 (Angels rescue believers from the four corners of the
>   earth after a trumpet is sounded)

Paul talks about the "trumpet of God" in 1-cor 15:52  and 1-Thess 4:16

1 Thessalonians:4.16

> For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the
>   voice of an archangel, and with the **trumpet of God**. And the dead
>   in Christ will rise first.

But in the scripture below he refers to a last Trumpet. 
1 Corinthians:15.52

> in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, **at the last trumpet. For the
>   trumpet will sound**, and the **dead will be raised incorruptible**, and we
>   shall be changed.

**QUESTION:
For there to be a last trumpet, there had to be preceding trumpets.**

**1) What is this "Last trumpet" that Paul is referring to**

**2) Was there evidence of a "Last trumpet" in Pharisaical Judaism, or in the prophecy teachings of the Torah.**

Comment: Personally, I doubt that these texts are related that precisely.

Comment: What reason is there to assume *(a)* the trumpets in the Revelation were literal trumpets, and *(b)* that any of them is what Paul had in mind? I don't see how this can be answered without resorting to sheer opinion.

Comment: @MarkEdward  Jesus said "not one jot or iota of the law or the prophets would pass till all is fulfilled".  This means that even the stories have parallels with future events. E.g in Jos 6:20, after the sound of the seventh trumpet, the wall of Jericho fell. In Rev, after the seventh trumpet, all the cities of the nations fell and all the Kingdoms of the earth became Yeshua's.

Comment: @MarkEdward Trumpets of the end are referenced in Joel 2:1, Zephaniah 1:16, Zechariah 9:14, Isaiah 18:3 and most importantly Ps 47:5 and Isaiah 27:13

Comment: @MarkEdward  So it isn't fair for you to down vote the question. I'm a student of Bible prophecy. Paul mentions the last Trumpet in 1 cor 15:52. LAST TRUMPET!!  How can there be a last if there weren't other trumpets. Paul knew about this trumpets due to his scholarship in the the scriptures. But through John, we get a clearer picture of the way the trumpet prophecies of the Psalms and other books will be fulfilled.  So please give me a chance. Give my question a chance. Thanks.

Comment: It's not about giving your question a chance. It's about people who submit questions to this site respecting its policies - including the policy that we do not answer opinion based questions.

Comment: @PeterKirkpatrick  ok vote to close the question.

Comment: @MarkEdward please vote to close the question as off topic.

Comment: @user20490, let me clarify in case you have misunderstood. Your specific question has been downvoted, but not necessarily the underlying topic. I suggest you read the guidelines and see if you can find a more neutral way of asking the question. (For example, I think the second part, asking if "last trumpet" literature exists outside the NT, is the beginnings of a great question.)

Comment: @user20490  This is an important question AS IS. Sorry to see it was killed off. (It is much more important what the scriptures say about trumpets than what they use at Roman festivals).

Comment: As to the background of trumpets we certainly have both the conquest of Canaan and the Feast of Trumpets to consider. The bottom line is that it is about Daniel's 70th Seven, which contrary to popular opinion was not delayed for thousands of years but in fact occurred in 66-73AD. The war was God's means of punishing the non-elect Jews for their consistent violation of Torah. The elect, new covenant Jews were then martyred to reign with Christ.

Comment: 2Ti 2:12 KJV - 12 If we suffer, we shall also reign with him: if we deny him, he also will deny us:
Rev 20:6 KJV - 6 Blessed and holy is he that hath part in the first resurrection: on such the second death hath no power, but they shall be priests of God and of Christ, and shall reign with him a thousand years.

Comment: Jesus returned circa 70AD and raised the dead from hADES, judged them and the elect Jews are now in God's sky kingdom reigning with Christ. The elect Jews were watching when he returned; the rest were unprepared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fifth, sixth and seven trumpets are the first, second and third woe respectively it is written:

Revelation 8:13

13 And I beheld, and heard an angel flying through the midst of heaven, saying with a loud voice, Woe, woe, woe, to the inhabiters of the earth by reason of the other voices of the trumpet of the three angels, which are yet to sound!
In Revelation 9:7, 16 these woes are related to battles, wars.  Revelation 11 is the seventh trumpet or the third woe. After the third woe the kingdom of the Messiah is set up on the earth:

Revelation 11:14,15

14 The second woe is past; and, behold, the third woe cometh quickly.
15 And the seventh angel sounded; and there were great voices in heaven, saying, The kingdoms of this world are become the kingdoms of our Lord, and of his Christ; and he shall reign for ever and ever.
We have the three world wars: 
Between the second and third world war Israel is back to there homeland. 
Between the second and third woe ( that is between the sixth and seventh trumpets) , the Angel of the covenant descends with a shout and seven thunders utter their voices and declares that the end of days:

Revelation 10:1-7

1 And I saw another mighty angel come down from heaven, clothed with a cloud: and a rainbow was upon his head, and his face was as it were the sun, and his feet as pillars of fire:
2 And he had in his hand a little book open: and he set his right foot upon the sea, and his left foot on the earth,
3 And cried with a loud voice, as when a lion roareth: and when he had cried, seven thunders uttered their voices.
4 And when the seven thunders had uttered their voices, I was about to write: and I heard a voice from heaven saying unto me, Seal up those things which the seven thunders uttered, and write them not.
5 And the angel which I saw stand upon the sea and upon the earth lifted up his hand to heaven,
6 And sware by him that liveth for ever and ever, who created heaven, and the things that therein are, and the earth, and the things that therein are, and the sea, and the things which are therein, that there should be time no longer:
7 But in the days of the voice of the seventh angel, when he shall begin to sound, the mystery of God should be finished, as he hath declared to his servants the prophets.

This angel clothed with a cloud, a rainbow over his head is the Angel of the covenant, rainbow represents the covenant, this coming has to do with the mystery of the rapture and the going away of the bride, the rapture. 
Between the second and third woe also the two witnesses of revelation 11 appear and they witness in Jerusalem, the sealing of the 144,000 Jews. 
Out of the church ages come the seals. Out of the seals come the trumpets, out of the trumpets come the vials. The seventh trumpet is also connected to the seventh vial, the battle of amagedon.

Revelation 16:17-21

17 And the seventh angel poured out his vial into the air; and there came a great voice out of the temple of heaven, from the throne, saying, It is done.
18 And there were voices, and thunders, and lightnings; and there was a great earthquake, such as was not since men were upon the earth, so mighty an earthquake, and so great.
19 And the great city was divided into three parts, and the cities of the nations fell: and great Babylon came in remembrance before God, to give unto her the cup of the wine of the fierceness of his wrath.
20 And every island fled away, and the mountains were not found.
21 And there fell upon men a great hail out of heaven, every stone about the weight of a talent: and men blasphemed God because of the plague of the hail; for the plague thereof was exceeding great.
The sixth vial gathers them to battle of amagedon, the beast and his armies and Christ descends with his army in Revelation 19.
The Last trump is connected to revelation 10 and sounds before the third woe of judgment, evening wrath, the great day of the battle of the almighty. 
The last trump is connected with the three fold mystery of his coming, connected to the shout, voice of the archangel and the trump call of God. 
The shout is a midnight cry message. Let me interject here and say between the second world war and third world war they invented the doomsday clock to tell us the time. 
The midnight time message also comes in the season Israel gathers to her home land before the battle of Ezekiel 38, 39
Matthew 25:6

6 And at midnight there was a cry made, Behold, the bridegroom cometh; go ye out to meet him.
The voice of the archangel brings the ressurection of the dead, in type:

Matthew 27:50-53

50 Jesus, when he had cried again with a loud voice, yielded up the ghost.
51 And, behold, the veil of the temple was rent in twain from the top to the bottom; and the earth did quake, and the rocks rent;
52 And the graves were opened; and many bodies of the saints which slept arose,
53 And came out of the graves after his resurrection, and went into the holy city, and appeared unto many.
To give other scripture connected to the ressurection of the dead in Christ:

Isaiah 26:19-21

19 Thy dead men shall live, together with my dead body shall they arise. Awake and sing, ye that dwell in dust: for thy dew is as the dew of herbs, and the earth shall cast out the dead.
20 Come, my people, enter thou into thy chambers, and shut thy doors about thee: hide thyself as it were for a little moment, until the indignation be overpast.
21 For, behold, the LORD cometh out of his place to punish the inhabitants of the earth for their iniquity: the earth also shall disclose her blood, and shall no more cover her slain.

This Isaiah scripture talks of a resurrection and a rapture to be followed by the great wrath.
Scripture has compound revelation. The ressurrections are compounded thus in Daniel:
Daniel 12:1,2

1 And at that time shall Michael stand up, the great prince which standeth for the children of thy people: and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time thy people shall be delivered, every one that shall be found written in the book.
2 And many of them that sleep in the dust of the earth shall awake, some to everlasting life, and some to shame and everlasting contempt.

The trump call is a voice calling come up hither, we have just read of it in Isaiah 26:20, a call to hide them from the coming indignation. It was typed in John after the message to the seven churches, prefiguring the seven church ages, for the trump call of God comes at the end of the seventh church age, for seven is a number of completion, in type:

Revelation 4:1

1 After this I looked, and, behold, a door was opened in heaven: and the first voice which I heard was as it were of a trumpet talking with me; which said, Come up hither, and I will shew thee things which must be hereafter.
These things are deep mysteries only to be revealed by the Holy Spirit, the giver of His word, for God must be his own interpreter. Man camps himself in schools of thought, private interpretation, thereby failing to understand by the events around him the fulfilment of the scripture.
Indeed it is a great mystery.

Comment: Why the down vote. Some people just behave so troll-like.  Because they don't like the question, they equally don't like any answers.

Comment: Thanks. The response is understandable. What I have tried to do is to broaden the scope and and perspective of the reader putting into account the rest of the scriptures connected to the trump call.